# How can i convert json file from labelme interface to png or image format file?

Tags: json, image, png, multilabel-classification, vgg-net

When i used the labeling the images from labelme interface as output i get json file.but i need to in image format like png,bmp,jpeg after labeling. can anyone suggest me any code ?

import json
from PIL import Image

```
with open('your,json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    # Load the file path from  the json
    imgpath = data['yourkey']
    
    # Place the image path into the open method
    img = Image.open(imgpath)
```

Comment: I don't think there is enough information in your question to answer you. You have `imgpath` which I presume is a filename? So do you have a file in your filesystem with that name or not? If not, where is the image that you want to load please? If you do have an image with that name in your filesystem, what happens when you run your code? And can you open that image with other applications?

Comment: @MarkSetchell labelme produce a json file that cointains multiple information, one of that is the image it self.  One way to export the json file is to use `label_file = labelme.LabelFile(filename=filename)` followed by `img = labelme.utils.img_data_to_arr(label_file.imageData)`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [tutorial](https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme/tree/main/examples/tutorial#convert-to-dataset) of the original [repository](https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme/), you can use `labelme_json_to_dataset <<JSON_PATH>> -o <<OUTPUT_FOLDER_PATH>>`.

To run it on `python` / `jupyter`, you can use:

```
import os

def labelme_json_to_dataset(json_path):
    os.system("labelme_json_to_dataset "+json_path+" -o "+json_path.replace(".","_"))
```

If you need to do it for multiple images, just loop the function.

---

Based on the [issue](https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme/issues/772#issuecomment-931360748), labelme_json_to_dataset behavior can be reimplemented by using either labelme2voc.py or labelme2coco.py.

---

You also could use other implementation like [labelme2Datasets](https://github.com/veraposeidon/labelme2Datasets//blob/main/README.en.md)

---

You also can implement your own modification of labelme_json_to_dataset using `labelme` library. Basically, you use `label_file = labelme.LabelFile(filename=filename)` followed by `img = labelme.utils.img_data_to_arr(label_file.imageData)`. An example of a process would be like this:

```py
import labelme

import os
import glob

def labelme2images(input_dir, output_dir, force=False, save_img=False, new_size=False):
    """
    new_size_width, new_size_height = new_size
    """
    if save_img:
        _makedirs(path=osp.join(output_dir, "images"), force=force)
        if new_size:
            new_size_width, new_size_height = new_size
    
    print("Generating dataset")
    
    filenames = glob.glob(osp.join(input_dir, "*.json"))
        
    for filename in filenames:
        # base name
        base = osp.splitext(osp.basename(filename))[0]

        label_file = labelme.LabelFile(filename=filename)

        img = labelme.utils.img_data_to_arr(label_file.imageData)
        h, w = img.shape[0], img.shape[1]

        if save_img:
            if new_size:
                img_pil = Image.fromarray(img).resize((new_size_height, new_size_width))
            else:
                img_pil = Image.fromarray(img)
                
            img_pil.save(osp.join(output_dir, "images", base + ".jpg"))
```

Comment: this is a demo not how you should do it for large batches of images

Comment: this is much better than your unedited answer. I have removed my downvote.